# vuejs2 change method not working currently

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have project working with vuejs2 
and this is the html code

```html
<input @keyup='check_item_offer(arrayresult.id, arrayresult.unit_id, arrayresult.qty, key, 16)' v-model='arrayresult.qty' />
```

and this is the `check_item_offer` code inside vuejs2 methods

```js
check_item_offer:function(item_id ,unit_id, quantity, key, tax) {
  this.taxss = tax;
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: path + 'check_item_offer',
    data: {
      item_id: item_id,
      unit_id: unit_id,
      quantity: quantity
    },
    success:(data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if(data != '') {
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: path + 'get_item_data',
          data: {
            item_id: item_id,
            unit_id: unit_id
          },
          success:(datas) => {
            data['item_sale_offer_detale_price'] = data['item_sale_offer_detale_price'] * (1 + this.taxss / 100);
            datas = datas * (1 + this.taxss / 100);
            var qty = this.arrayresults[key].qty;
            var old_price = datas;
            var offer_quantity = data['item_sale_offer_detale_quantity'];
            var remain = this.arrayresults[key].qty % data['item_sale_offer_detale_quantity'];
            var new_price = data['item_sale_offer_detale_price'];
            var item_with_new_price_quantity = qty - remain;
            var price_with_offers = (item_with_new_price_quantity / offer_quantity) * new_price;
            var price_without_offers = old_price * remain;
            var total_price = (price_with_offers + price_without_offers) / qty;
            this.arrayresults[key].item_smallest_unit_selling_price = total_price;
            this.arrayresults[key].items_quantity_selling_price = total_price;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

everything working so good

If I change the `arrayresult.qty` using keyup it will working fine 
but if I change the `arrayresult.qty` using ajax call any another way `keyup` it will not run the `check_item_offer` till I go to the input and press any key

How can I run the `check_item_offer` even if i change the `arrayresult.qty` even ajax call ?
Thanks

Comment: comment all code after `this.taxss = tax;` and check once again ? Also check value of `item_id,unit_id,quantity,key,tax` in console.log(item_id,unit_id,quantity,key,tax) and share  ?

Comment: the change come after this.taxss = tax; in the ajax call

Comment: aah..the common problem of `this` reference...`this` inside ajax success callback is entirely different than what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to fire the function, *check_item_offer*, set to the keyup event for changes in the v-model,  *arrayresult.qty*, value programmatically, *ajax calls*, then you need to set a *watch* for the v-model variable like so

```
watch:{
    'arrayresult.qty'(newVal, oldVal){
        this.check_item_offer(itemId, unitId, newVal, key, 16);
    }
}
```

For more info on vuejs [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Comment: it didnot work with me but if i change the watch like this  watch:
 {
  arrayresults(newVal, oldVal){
   alert("Asdfasdf");
   //this.check_item_offer(itemId, unitId, newVal, key, 16);
  }
 }, its work

Comment: i need to watch arrayresult.qty from any change

Comment: Can you check this pen. A use-case has been mocked up. https://codepen.io/zapping-the-selector/pen/GRKGXYr?editors=1011